# choose flutter build apk release?(abi)

Tags: flutter, google-play, release

i need upload my release apk generated by flutter to the Google play store. When i run "flutter build apk --release" the response is and apk but the size is 21MB(Based in the documentation is a FAT apk that includes all abi's apk).

```
javier.hospital@COBOADM-UD-P01 Flutter-APP-BODYTECH % flutter build apk --release                                                              

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      20,5s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk (21.9MB).
```

I found out othe command "flutter build apk  --split-per-abi", this commands generate 3 apks with 8mb size. I think that is a good option beacause i need that the size of my application are small.

```
javier.hospital@COBOADM-UD-P01 Flutter-APP-BODYTECH % flutter build apk --split-per-abi

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      12,7s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (8.4MB).
```

The problem is when i try sign any of this 3 apks, it's not possible to sign an the code error is  "**jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 5654 but got 5205 bytes)**".

My question is that when i upload the first apk (21MB) to google play, the user download only 8mb apk?. or is neccesary upload 3 abi apks for the user to download only 8 mb?

In which case it is so, what way is there to sign an apk generated only for a specific abi?.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uploading the App bundle is the recommended method by Google.
I always use the App bundle to upload my Apps to the playstore.

> My question is that when i upload the first apk (21MB) to google play,
> the user download only 8mb apk?

Yes the user only has to download an 8MB file

Read More about App bundle here https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle